# vagrant puppet symbolic link issue

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, puppet, symlink

I used the below puppet configuration for my vagrant file

```
exec {"apt-get update":
  path => "/usr/bin",
}

package {"apache2":
  ensure  => present,
  require => Exec["apt-get update"],
}

service { "apache2":
  ensure  => "running",
  require => Package["apache2"],
}

file {"/var/www/demo":
  ensure => "link",
  target => "/www",
  require => Package["apache2"],
  notify => Service["apache2"],
}
```

But I got the 403 error " You don't have permission to access /demo/ on this server." when trying to access [my guest ip address]/demo. May someone advise ?

Answer (score 0):

The apache process does not have access to your `/www` docroot.

You likely want to create this location with permissions that permit all users to read the web data. Do **not** make the `www-data` (or whatever user runs apache) the owner of the docroot - you don't want your web content writeable, as a rule.

Puppet *can* manage ownership for that whole tree, but that is rather expensive. It is often preferable to make sure that permissions are appropriate right after provisioning.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the target into "/vagrant/www"